# Move USB Stick Booted from to Another USB Port after Boot

Tags: boot, usb, mount

I have installed Ubuntu on 32GB USB 3.0 flash drive (not Live/Install like with UUI, but regular install including grub, from DVD).

However, my motherboard will not boot from USB 3 ports, only USB 2. What I want to know is if there's a way to let it boot and load X from the USB 2 port and then do something like unmount, move USB stick to USB3 port, and then remount somehow and have system still work normally. I didn't do a swap partition, so it's just / I think would be the issue.

Thanks for any help in doing this (or confirming it can't be done).

Answer (score 3):

I also have a PC that cannot boot from USB3. What I did was installed the Grub and /Boot to a USB2 Stick and then the rest of Ubuntu to an USB3 stick. By boot I press the F12 key for choosing to boot from the USB2 stick and from the boot menu there choosing any other installed system including Ubuntu. I sure hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the interesting concept. Will it work if you move the 2 USBs to a different PC? Does it matter if you plugin the USB 3 drive to a different USB 3 port in the same PC? You may want to elaborate a little on how you did the install in two different USBs.